# Visualizing ConvNet filters using my own fine-tuned network resulting in a "NoneType" when running: K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I have a fine-tuned network that I created which uses vgg16 as it's base.  I am following section 5.4.2 Visualizing CovNet Filters in [Deep Learning With Python](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python) (which is very similar to the guide on the Keras blog to visualize convnet filters [here](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html)).

The guide simply uses the vgg16 network.  My fine tuned model uses the vgg16 model as the base, for example:

`model.summary()`

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
======================================================================= vgg16 (Model)                (None, 4, 4, 512)         14714688
________________________________________________________________________ flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0
________________________________________________________________________ dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 256)               2097408
________________________________________________________________________ dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 771
======================================================================== Total params: 16,812,867 Trainable params: 16,812,867 Non-trainable params: 0

I'm running into an issue when I run this line: 
`grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]` where when I use my fine tuned network I get a result that's a "NoneType"

Here is the code from the guide:

```
> from keras.applications import VGG16 from keras import backend as K
> 
> model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
>               include_top=False)
> 
> layer_name = 'block3_conv1' filter_index = 0
> 
> layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output loss =
> K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])
> 
> grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]
```

To reproduce the on my fine tuned model, I've used the **exact** same code, **except** I obviously changed the model that I imported:

`model = keras.models.load_model(trained_models_dir + 'fine_tuned_model.h5')`

...and I also had to index into the nested Model object (my first layer is a Model object as is shown above) to get the 'block2_con1' layer:

```
my_Model_object = 'vgg16'
layer_name = 'block3_conv1'
filter_index = 0

layer_output = 
model.get_layer(my_Model_object).get_layer(layer_name).output
```

any idea why running `grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]` on my fine tuned network would result in a "NoneType"??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**  I had to use: `grads = K.gradients(loss, model.get_layer(my_Model_object).get_layer('input_1').input)[0]`

instead of just `grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]`

which is confusing because both `model.get_layer(my_Model_object).get_layer('input_1').input)[0]` 
and 
`model.input[0]` print the same thing and are of the same type.